# greatest common divisor of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $k$ is a field, and assume that $f(x)$, and $g(x)$ are coprime polynomials in the polynomial ring $k[x]$. Then, there exist polynomials $a(x)$, and $b(x)$ both in $k[x]$ such that $$af +bg =1.$$ I want to prove that ${\rm{deg}}(a) < {\rm{deg}}(g)$, and that ${\rm{deg}}(b) < {\rm{deg}}(f).$ Is this obvious? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Note that, for any $a_0,b_0$ such that $a_0f+b_0g=1$, all solutions $(a,b)$ to $af+bg=1$ satisfy $a=a_0-gh$ and $b=b_0+fh$ for some $h(x)\in k[x]$.  Choose $h$ wisely (and observe that this $h$ is unique, whence the condition $\deg(a)<\deg(g)$ gives rise to a unique pair $(a,b)$).

Comment: You can't prove $a$ and $b$ have those properties. What you can prove is that there exist $a$ and $b$ that have those properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $f(x)=x+1$, $g(x)=x+2$, $a(x)=-x-3$, and $b(x)=x+2$, then you get 
$a f + b g = 1$ and $\deg f = \deg g = \deg a = \deg b =1$, which don't satisfy your conclusion; but clearly $a = -1$ and $b = 1$ will. Your real question should be "do there exists an $a$ and a $b$ such that $a f + b g = 1$ with 
$\deg a < \deg g$ and $\deg b < \deg f$".

We know that there exists polynomials $\alpha, \beta \in k[x]$ such that 
$$\alpha f + \beta g = 1 \tag{1.}$$

Then there exists polynomials $A, a \in k[x]$ for which 
$\alpha = Ag + a$ and for which $\deg a < \deg g$
Note that this implies

$$\deg(af) < \deg(fg) \tag{2.}$$

Also, there exists polynomials $B, b \in k[x]$ for which 
$\beta = Bf + b$ and for which $\deg b < \deg f$
Note that this implies

$$\deg(bg) < \deg(fg) \tag{3.}$$

Substituting and rearranging, we get

\begin{align}
   \alpha f + \beta g &= 1 \\
   (Ag + a)f + (Bf + b) g &= 1 \\
   Afg + af + Bfg + bg &= 1 \\
   af + bg &= 1 -(A+B)fg
\end{align}

But $\deg(af + bg) < \deg(fg)$ and, if $A+B \ne 0$, then 
$\deg(1-(A+B)fg) \ge \deg(fg)$.

It follows that $A+B=0$ and $af + bg = 1$.